# PHP, How to Filtering

Tags: php, netbeans-8

I have a list like this in my php file and I want to filter them. I am going url for this php and use it, in jQuery with Ajax to do my auto complete

```
[{"name":"Fredericksburg", "value":"Fredericksburg"},
{"name":"Harrisonburg", "value":"Harrisonburg"},
{"name":"Lynchburg", "value":"Lynchburg"},
{"name":"Petersburg", "value":"Petersburg"},
{"name":"Norfolk", "value":"Norfolk"},
{"name":"Lexington", "value":"Lexington"}]
```

Nothing else is in there. How can I filter them?

Comment: Need more description.  What is filter, how, what is the end result?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand very well what's the question here, but you can use array_filter in PHP, as long as you put the above mentioned elements in a variable (like $array):

```
function test_filter($var)
{
    if($var == something) 
        return($var);
}

var_dump(array_filter($array, "test_filter"));
```

Comment: Basically, I am using this list with my jQuery with Ajax for autocomplete search. For Example if I type L or l in my text box, any word that start with l should only be display, instead it's going to the end of my list and print every thing out from A-Z.  Because the list in my PHP file is not filter. I just want it to return the specific word I am looking for. In order for that to happen I need to filter the list in my php file